# How can i know the original file name from google drive link using c# code

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api

I need to extract the original file name of the files stored in Google drive by using the shared link provided for the file.

For eg: I have a file name Image.png and link will be: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1xYe18oaj2kpF6S--Vn_iJgdpKifTPvpkniZkV1-fpFc/edit?usp=sharing

If I extract this link embedded in my email then how can i figure out its original name "Image.png" using C#.Net code?

Comment: How are you getting this shared link? If your are not taking this shared link from your file from google drive, browse its metadata of the file and see if you can find the shared link anywhere. If you find the shared link in metadata, then write a query based on the shared link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL that you mentioned contains the `file ID` of the shared file. If you have access to that file, you can retrieve the ***File name aka `title`*** by just getting the metadata of the file using drive api.

**File ID : `1xYe18oaj2kpF6S--Vn_iJgdpKifTPvpkniZkV1-fpFc`**

Try the below code. Hope you know about the authentication process. If not see the below links.

```
public static void printFile(DriveService service) {
    try {

      String fileId = "1xYe18oaj2kpF6S--Vn_iJgdpKifTPvpkniZkV1-fpFc";
      File file = service.Files.Get(fileId).Execute();
      Console.WriteLine("Title: " + file.Title);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    }
  }
```

Check the .NET Example given here: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Comment: Hi Prem, Can you please provide me the authentication code for this.. I couldn't authenticate to google drive it is just failing.